# works in jfiddle but not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

http://jsfiddle.net/9cSdm/21/

Here is a fiddle I´d like to use in a project.

It works perfectly in the fiddle but when i try to use it in my project I get error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'cookie'"

I cant understand why? Whats the difference between the fiddle and the browser?

Thanks!

```
$(function () {


    $(".p").click(function () {
        save($(this).text());
    });
});

function save(i) {
    var foobar = new Array();


    var cock = unescape($.cookie('cockie'));


    if (cock != 'null') foobar = cock.split(';');


    foobar.push(i);


    $.cookie('cockie', escape(foobar.join(';')), {
        expires: 1337
    });


    $('#cockieResult').text("Kakan: " + foobar.toString());
}

function clearCockie() {
    $.cookie("cockie", null);
    $('#cockieResult').text("");
}
```

Comment: Did you import the cookie jQuery plugin in your project ?

Comment: `if (cock != 'null') cock.split(';');` dear god

Comment: You need http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: There is a special plugin I need to add? I had no idea...Is it this?
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Guess I have to study some more...

Answer (score 1):

You should add [jquery.cookie.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js) file to your code.

Expand section "External Resources" is JSFiddle and you'll see that it was imported to your script:

[image: JSFiddle]

Comment: Thank You!
So i download the the file to the same folder as the other js-file and add a link like this: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: @user2915962 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Another problem showed up though.
Im working on an experimental webshop and the code is for saving the items the user clicks on. The thing is that my itmes are displayed in an iframe (i.e another page on my site). The above code doesnt seem to fetch the cookies from the iframe...

Even though i´ve given the the class of "p".